# sql inner join where and

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

```
tbl user
    +--------+--------+
    | UserID | Name   |
    +--------+--------+
    | 1      | John   |
    | 2      | Anny   |
    | 3      | Andy   |
    | 4      | Tom    |
    +--------+--------+

tbl rol
    +--------+--------+
    | RolID | Name    |
    +--------+--------+
    | 1      | Manager|
    | 2      | Lead   |
    | 3      | Tester |
    | 4      | Develop|
    +--------+--------+


tbl user_rol
    +--------+--------+
    | UserID | RolID  |
    +--------+--------+
    | 1      | 1      |
    | 1      | 2      |
    | 1      | 4      |
    | 2      | 1      |
    | 3      | 3      |
    +--------+--------+
```

I have a List of parameters 1,2,4

```
SELECT u.UserID,Name
  FROM [user] u
  WHERE u.UserID in(
    SELECT ur2.UserID 
    FROM user_rol ur2
    WHERE ur2.ROlID IN(1,2,4) 
    GROUP BY ur2.UserID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ur2.RolID)=3
    )
```

The response will be:

```
 +--------+--------+
 | UserID | Name   |
 +--------+--------+
 | 1      | John   |
```

but if my parameters will be 1,2,3,4 will not work, but i need the response to be like previous

The problem is in count I did not know how much exists in the intermediate table user_rol.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What are you trying to do?  There are no users with all four values, so it is unclear what "like previous" is supposed to mean.

Comment: How your final result should be?

Comment: I think when input is `1,2,3,4` there should not be any records selected

Comment: Please revise your question to make it more understandable. For example, what does "like previous" mean in "I need the response to be like previous"? Also, what do you mean by "input"? I see no input. I see example tables and a query. Instead of answering my questions in the comments, please take a few minutes to revise your question.

Comment: Adding another role in the `IN` clause of the above query should not make any difference. What is the revised query?

Comment: move the condition in `where` clause to `Having` clause like this  `HAVING Count(CASE WHEN ur2.rolid IN( 1, 2, 4 ) THEN 1 END) = Count(*)`

Comment: also `tbl rol` is not needed in your "question" and not in your query

Comment: Best would be to paramaterize both values the list of ids and the count and pass in two values, alternatively you could select from role for those Ids...`having count(ur2.rolId) = (Select count(*) from rol where rolID in (1,2,4))`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from you question, but it seems to me are looking to output any user that has more than one role listed in the user_rol table. Here is how you would do that:

```
SELECT user.userid, user.name
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_rol
ON user.userid = user_rol.userid
GROUP BY user.userid, user.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35288d